# Speech Recognition Offline

Tags: python-3.x, speech-recognition

everyone, I am learning speech recognition in python and I am quite interesting whether it can be used offline. I mean, we use:

```
rec = sr.Recognizer()
with sr.Microphone() as source:
    audio = rec.listen(source)
    said = rec.recognize_google(audio)
print(said)
```

to recognize our speech, however recognise_google() doesn't work without internet connection. Is there any other way, that works offline? I'll be grateful if someone helps...

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that you're using the python [speech recognition library](https://github.com/Uberi/speech_recognition). This library can be used with CMU Sphinx, which works offline.

The library [pocketsphinx](https://github.com/bambocher/pocketsphinx-python) is setup to work offline by default, so might be a good choice if youre just getting started.